# number validaiton - javascript regex

Tags: regex

I've come up with this regular expression to validate a number which can have Maximum length-13 (including decimal points),Maximum no of decimal points-3,Maximum length of a whole number-12.

```
^(\d{1,12}([.]\d{1,1})?|\d{1,11}([.]\d{1,2})?|\d{1,10}([.]\d{1,3})?)$
```

Could anyone tell me if my approach is correct or give me a better solution?

Comment: Your regex matches `123456789012.3` **which is a total of 14**, but you said *"number which can have Maximum length-13 (including decimal points)"*... so... it has 12 whole dec. numbers but `.3` are extras...

Comment: Can you have a 0 digit fractional part?  i.e.  Would `0.` be valid?

Comment: Just in case, if this is an input you can use `type="number"` in your markup instead of playing with regexes :)

Comment: I'm sorry, did not count '.'. So excluding dot length should be 13 including decimal places . 123456789012.3 is fine.

Answer (score 3):

This would also work:

```
^(?=.{1,13}$)(\d{1,12})(\.\d{1,3})?$
```

Uses positive look ahead to match the entire string length is ok.
Then it uses a group to match from 1 - 12 digits
Then there's an optional group to match a decimal followed by 1-3 digits.

Edited: Simplified since the rules don't allow a 13 digit integer-part

Comment: Amazing and bulletproof.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks.  Wouldn't have been so simple if you hadn't pointed out the "no 13 digit integer part" issue

Comment: Thanks Tibrogargan. Considering '.' , I guess it should be ^(?=.{1,14}$)(\d{1,12})(\.\d{1,3})?$.